# Using Dialogflow Inline Editor

Tags: dialogflow-es

I am a beginning user of Dialogflow and have two questions about 
the use of the Inline Editor:

1 - Where are the files shown by the Inline Editor stored?  I assume they are stored within the Firebase database but not certain.

2 - Is any explicit "save" action required when using the Inline
Editor?

Thanks for any help.
Jim

Answer (score 1):

1. The functions you write in the Editor are saved as  [FireBase Cloud
   Functions](https://firebase.google.com/products/functions/) which is a service of the Firebase. These
   functions are called whenever you hit a fulfilment request and
   Dialogflow uses free tier configurations. But you can refer to
   [Firebase pricing](https://firebase.google.com/pricing/) if you want to upgrade.
2. There is a save button below the Editor to save the contents. Until
   clicked, the contents will be lost if the page is reloaded.

Comment: This is a good answer, but the editor is actually backed by Firebase Functions, not Cloud Functions. They're similar but distinct.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Edited my answer

Answer (score 0):

The inline editor directly uploads it content to your firebase functions on the Google project you are using for your DialogFlow agent from which you are uploading. This code in turn gets saved in the Google cloud function as firebase is built on Google cloud. You can find the code only over there. you can even edit directly in your Google cloud functions.
Hope this helps